# How to construct GmailService in web app when using .AddGoogle() in Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

The goal: generate a draft email with body content and attachments and drop it into my current user's GMail account.

The environment: ASP.NET Core 3.1

I'm already using Google Authentication in my web app and am successfully requesting the Gmail Compose scope:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        IConfigurationSection googleAuthSection = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
        options.ClientId = googleAuthSection["ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = googleAuthSection["ClientSecret"];
        options.Scope.Add(Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose);
    });
```

From the various samples online, this is what I've found I need to do to generate a draft and save it to a gmail account:

```
var draft = new Draft();
draft.Message = new Message();
draft.Message.Payload = new MessagePart { Body = new MessagePartBody { Data = "hello world".ToBase64Url() } };

var clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = _googleAuthSettings.ClientId,
    ClientSecret = _googleAuthSettings.ClientSecret
};
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    clientSecrets,
    new[] { Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose },
    user.Data.EmailAddress,
    CancellationToken.None);

var gservice = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.GmailService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Aeon"
    });

var createRequest = gservice.Users.Drafts.Create(draft, user.Data.EmailAddress);
```

The problem is that the call to `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` is a brand new auth request that pops a new browser window to auth against Google (which doesn't work because redirect urls and such). I've already authed the user through my existing startup/login process.

The two `GmailService` constructors take either no arguments or this `BaseClientService.Initializer` class, which itself takes a `Google.Apis.Services.IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer` object. In the sample above, the `UserCredential` class implements this interface. How do I use my existing login process' credentials to construct a gmail service? Alternatively, is there a way to do what I'm looking to do without having to construct a `GmailService` instance?

Comment: which doesn't work because redirect urls and such)  <-- do you have an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to use `Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc` for web services, as `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` can not be used to create the authorization flow for web apps.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on [OAuth in Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc):

> After creating a new web application project in your IDE, add the right Google.Apis NuGet package for [Drive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/), [YouTube](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.youtube.v3/), or the other service you want to use. Then, add the [Google.Apis.Auth.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.MVC/) package.

The page also demonstrates an ASP.NET MVC application that queries a Google API service.

If you want to deploy GmailService on the web you need to make use of [the Google.Apis.Auth.MVC package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.MVC/) to make an implementation of the controllers.

Also from the source for the [`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` class](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/a610e6f36d994fd8e81cd6ed9e61d9c603fd154e/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs):

> ```
> /// This class is only suitable for client-side use, as it starts a local browser 
> /// that requires user interaction.
> /// Do not use this class when executing on a web server, or any cases where the 
> /// authenticating end-user is not able to do directly interact with a launched 
> /// browser.
> ```

#### References:

- [OAuth 2.0 | API Client Library for .NET | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth)
- [NuGet Gallery | Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc 1.46.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.MVC/)
- [google-api-dotnet-client/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/a610e6f36d994fd8e81cd6ed9e61d9c603fd154e/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs)

Comment: That package - Google.Apis.Auth.MVC - is only for .NET Framework 4.5+, and I'm using .NET Core 3.1. However, I did find [Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore/1.46.0?_src=template) which might be useful.

Comment: Update: Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore is only for up to Core 2.1 due to breaking changes in .NET Core 3's auth handling. To support Core 3, there's a beta library named [Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3/1.46.0-beta01?_src=template). Found that by googling the error message you get trying to use the first library and got it from [this GitHub issue link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1413) and then [this GitHub issue link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1434).